# How to make a page preloader similar to Apple's Mac page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slide, attr

If you have a look at Apple's Mac page on their website. http://www.apple.com/mac/
Their "body" displays an image in the center while the page is loading. After the page is fully loaded, their content fades in. If you use Chrome or Safari and open the Element Inspector, you'll see their body gets the `class="loaded revealed"` when the page is loaded. And that triggers the content to fade in. If you remove the classes, the content will fade out.

I'm looking for something similar to this for my website. I don't want the whole entire content to not display, I still want to display the header and footer. So basically I want the `div#content_area` to slide down on document ready... The only problem is, they don't use any kind of `display:none;` for their body. They're a bit more careful about that, because if the JS file fails, the content will still display.

How can I make this? They way they do it must be lightweight because anybody can write something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div#content_area').attr(class, loaded revealed);
});
```

All I need to do is add the `.slide()` function and hide the content until the page loads.

Comment: Yesterday I retagged this for you get you a little more attention; doesn't look like it helped much. Is my answer acceptable @user1090389?

Comment: It wasn't specifically what I was looking for. I will continue to work on this and will let you know...

Comment: Perhaps rephrase your question. With Javascript you have a solution provided. You were specifically seeking a non-hack no-JS answer for a smooth downgrade with script off, and there is none.

Comment: JavaScript is okay, but I want something like Apple's website. Nothing is hidden.

Comment: I am almost positive Apple is using Javascript. No?

Comment: Yes, they are. The question permits JavaScript just not hiding anything.

Comment: I'm spent then. Good luck. Post your answer when you find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have found out that Apple has all it's elements opacity set to 0. And on the body load, it adds the classes to the body and uses some basic CSS like this

```
div{
opacity:0;
}
body.loaded div {
opacity:1;
transition:etc.etc.;
}
```

Here's my version, http://jsfiddle.net/dqUaX/1/

What's great about it is:

1. Opacity is considered a CSS3 attribute so if a browser is outdated the content won't hide.
2. I am actually using jQuery to set the opacity to 0 so even if the user has a css3 browser, but has JavaScript disabled, the content will still display.
3. Since you'll need CSS3 to hide the div, I used a giant DATA URI for the background image so it doesn't have to load.

Pretty awesome no?

You must put the script before the end of the `<body>` closing tag...

Comment: congratulations. you are still using javascript though, and Opacity accomplishes the same thing as `display:none`. Curious... can you explain #3 a little bit more?

Comment: IE6 and 7 cannot render DATA URIs that long... Like I stated in my question, a little JavaScript is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Setup your DIV of content right where you want it... setup the image you want to be a placeholder right over the top (with absolute if possible/necessary).

In CSS use the `z-index` property to keep the image above the other.

What you do then is make the IMG a `display:none;` property, and then as they page is loading you can turn it on with jQuery... so with JS the placeholder shows and sits above... without JS, the image placeholder is invisible, and the user simply sees the content DIV as it loads.

That make sense?

Comment: I still don't understand how the content will hide even if the image is on top of it?

Comment: make sure the overlaying photo's block container is opaque, with a larger z-index to sit on top... you could use jQuery to set the background color CSS property dynamically by grabbing the page's background color to make it match and look seemless.

Comment: just to restate, the point is if you want the content to display properly without JS, to leave it where it should be... no sliding, no negative margins, no invisible or display:none... just to make an opaque overlay IF the user has JS enabled, and to slide it out of the way when the page load completes - the end result is the same in that it looks like your content has just arrived. :)

Comment: Yes, that is what I want, but I also want the content to slide in.

Comment: i guess what I'm saying is without scripting, how would you move/animate your content DIV? Don't know of any other way myself.