# Slide down a div on body load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slidedown, pageload

How can I have a div hide as the page is loading and then slide down once the page loads? I don't want to use CSS `display:none;`

Comment: whats wrong with using display:none, and are you doing raw javascript or using jquery?

Comment: Either or... The problem with `display:none` is that there is no backup in case the JS doesn't execute or the user has JS disabled. The content is just hidden

Comment: @user1090389 In the case "JS doesn't execute or the user has JS disabled", then how are you going to slide down the div without Javascript?

Comment: @emaillenin, he is right, I also have the same fear sometimes. He might want to 1)hide via JS, 2)show+slide. So in case JS is off, nothing will happen (but the users will be able to see the content)

Comment: @user1090389 Without javascript, how will you find out, if the page has been loaded completely?

Comment: @ajax333221 no his point is that, "the div must be hidden from the page" initially till the page is loaded completely.

Comment: @ajax333221 If JavaScript does not execute for whatever reason, the content is still there. It doesn't slide down or anything, its just there.

Comment: @emaillenin It's okay to use JavaScript to find out if the page has been loaded completely

Comment: Your requirements are paradox. Tell clearly. Option 1 - No javascript. What do you want to do?. Option 2 - Javascript is present. What do you want to do?

Comment: @emaillenin I don't mind using JavaScript, I just don't want to hide the DIV. Basically, I want a div to roll down on the page load.

Comment: @user1090389 If the div is not hidden initially, how will you roll it down? can you show any one example?

Comment: @emaillenin like http://apple.com/Mac  the content exists but isn't show until the page loads and if the JavaScript fails to execute the content loads normally

Comment: @user1090389 U mean those mac pictures are sliding down?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549743/a-page-preloader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This suits me better, although it does not slide down, fading in is good enough.
http://jsfiddle.net/dqUaX/1/

Answer (score 0):

Give this fiddle a try: http://jsfiddle.net/ahr3U/

This basically uses CSS3 to set up all the parameters of the transition, (the transition property makes the animation possible) and then just adds the visible class once the document has loaded to trigger the animation.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="notification">Page load complete...</div>
```

CSS:

```
#notification {
    background-color: #F00;
    color: #FFF;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
    width: 100%;
    transition: top 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: top 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.5s;
    -o-transition: top 0.5s;
}

#notification.visible {
    top: 0px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#notification").addClass("visible");
});
```