# jquery slidedown on page load

Tags: jquery, css, slide, slidedown

How can slide down a div with jquery on page load where css is set to display:none? I see a lot of solutions but none can slide div if css is set display:none. The best way is to hide it on load and after slidedown but the div have flash (show) when page is loading.

Comment: I asked something like this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550009/slide-down-a-div-on-body-load

Comment: What have you tried? What's not working? Sharing some code would be helpful :)

Answer (score 6):

You could try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hidden').slideDown(1000);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="hidden">This is the content</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{
 display:none;   
}
```

It slides down on page load.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wH7YU/)**

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#hidden_div_id').slideDown('slow');
```

this internally make use of `display:block`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found above as working solution. So here it is http://www.robertprice.co.uk/robblog/using-jquery-to-scroll-to-an-element/

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: ($('#element').offset().top)
},500);
```