# Slide Down in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking to gain a effect on my page similar to host-gators live chat thing, I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702912/jquery-slidedown-on-page-load) and this is similar to what I'm trying to achieve but there is one problem the `div` like starts at `height:1px` and slides the `div` down to its original height, what I want is for the `div`s height to always be the same and it slide down from the top of the page and not the top of the `div`, I hope this explains it well.

Comment: Also just in case this is important, my div is position:fixed;

Comment: the link is there just very invisible

Comment: i used the jquery slideDown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you mean is a `blind`-effect. Take a look here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/cZQTR/

I've written a small plugin for that fx:

```
jQuery.fn.blindToggle = function (duration, easing, complete) {
    return this.animate({
        marginTop: parseFloat(this.css('marginTop')) < 0 ? 0 : -this.outerHeight(true)
    }, jQuery.speed(duration, easing, complete));
};
```

**Update**

```
jQuery.fn.blindUp = function (duration, easing, complete) {
    return this.animate({
        marginTop: -this.outerHeight(true)
    }, jQuery.speed(duration, easing, complete));
};

jQuery.fn.blindDown = function (duration, easing, complete) {
    return this.animate({
        marginTop: 0
    }, jQuery.speed(duration, easing, complete));
};
```

**[demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cZQTR/8/)**

Comment: yes, thats what i want, but with that code how would i make it slide down? as your example slides up

Comment: Note : i am now using margin-left on the js so is slides from the left | ok, cool thanks, its working but i have one problem, i was using position fixed and this doesn't work with that, so i am happy to use relative but how would i keep the dive center if i am applying margin-left: 0 with the javascript?

Comment: @ConnorMiles try `left` instead of `margin-left`

Comment: im not sure what your getting at as i am on about in the javascript and in there i put marginLeft not margin-left? i replaced it with left and its not working atall

Comment: is it possible to use this with position:fixed; ?

Comment: @ConnorMiles I need a bit more code from you to give you a good answer ;-) Prepare a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and share the link here. Then I'll see what i can do for you...

Comment: @ConnorMiles Like this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/cZQTR/7/ ? I've added `position: relative;` and `left: -100%;` to your `div`.