# CSS3 loading screen called by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

While testing my web app for iOS, I noticed that CSS3 animations were hardware-accelerated and wanted to switch my loading screen over to CSS3 animations.

The loading screen was a simple `div` that covers the screen:

```
.loading{
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 10;
background-color:#000;
display: none;
}
```

The content of my page is loaded via AJAX. The loading `div` is shown when the page loads, and when the request is made again (so the AJAX request would be reloaded, updating the content). The way I did this was using:

```
$('.loading').show()
```

Before everything else, then `$('.loading').fadeOout()` once the AJAX request was finished.

Then with the reload button, I had the following set up:

```
$("#reload").on("click", function() {
    $('.loading').fadeIn()
    doAjax("http://google.com");
    $('.loading').delay(300).fadeOut()
});
```

That way, when the request was reloaded, it would fade in the loading screen, load the AJAX content, wait 300ms, and then fade out the `div`.

Now, what is the best way to transfer this all over to CSS3 animations? I was helped earlier on SO (by Duopixel) with this problem, and he was able to get this far: http://jsfiddle.net/E2Srk/

The problems with that solution are:

1. The `div` isn't shown on page load. This means there is a few second delay between showing the loading screen.
2. The loading screen doesn't fade in when the AJAX request is reloaded. It just shows, then fades out.

If anyone has any ideas on how to fix these problems, or has a better solution, that'd be great.
The

Comment: Maybe this will be of help, CSS3: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8676431/1090389

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Action 1: Enable Fade-In**

By removing transition in your .loading.animated class your fade-in problem will fix.

**Action 2: Enable 3 seconds delay to fade out**

To add 3 second delay I just put removeClass inside setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.loading').removeClass("animated");
},3000);
```

If you like to do it in jQuery style you can use this:

```
$('.loading').delay(3000).queue(function(next){
    $(this).removeClass("animated");
    next();
});
```

**Action 3: Disable Fade-In effect in Page Load**

To disable Fade-in in start I apply a trick by adding new class .firsttime to div which disabled the animation and then remove it after Ajax call, so all other calls will have fade in except first one ;)

**Action 4: Display Loading without delay on Start Up**

To show loading without any delay for first time I added .animated class to your div inside your html so it will show up right aways and won't wait to JavaScript!

**Action 5: Remove 3 seconds delay on Start Up**

To not delay first time loading, I added a property to doAjax function to check if it's the first time or not, and if it is, then just remove the class .animated otherwise, add 3 sec delay then delete the class.

Updated JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E2Srk/5/

I hope this fix all of your issues :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem with this is that I don't want the original div to fade in when the page loads. I just want it to fade out. Also, there is no delay on the reload loading screen.

Comment: Edits are great, adds the delay in :) But it's still applying the delay and fade to the animation that happens on load, which I don't want to happen. Should I use a seconds loading screen for that purpose, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I update the message to support 3 sec delay for fade out. Also I apply a trick to not fade in for first time :-)

Comment: Perfect ;D I feel like the delay is still being applied to the original loading screen though? Can you use that trick to only append it to the reload loading screen?

Comment: Do you want to remove 3 sec delay on Page Load but exist in all other ajax calls?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to happen. But there's also another problem with this approach, as I stated in the post. There is a few second delay between the loading screen being given the animated class, making it display. That means that parts of the page are shown loading in that few second gap. How can I fix this?

Comment: I just update my Answer :-) I fixed the start up delay for showing Loading as well as 3 sec delay! Please don't hesitate to ask for any other changes, I'll be more than happy to help.

Comment: Thank you!! You're very helpful, I'll let you know if I run into any other problems.